# small translation verification help

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I live in Germany since 1 year and I am super new to this forum and I was hoping someone can help verify this translation.

Its for a video I am making and I have written a simple translation

Hungry! -> Hungrig!

Someone Around -> Jemand In der Nahe

Is cooking -> Kocht

Go get some -> Geh weiter und ess

Comment: Please ask only one question per question and also be more specific about the context and what you already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hungry** is indeed **hungrig.**

Just "someone around" (don't you mean "someone **is** around"?) is indeed "jemand **ist** in der Nähe", although it is not too common. If however, you mean it as a question, something like **Is someone around?**, then this would be **Ist jemand da?** (usual one) or **Ist jemand in der Nähe?**.

**Cooking** is indeed **kochen**, so for example **He is cooking** translates to **Er kocht**.

**Go get some** would then translate to **Gehe los und hole etwas**, for example when you want to say to your friend **Go get some bananas**, that would be **Gehe los und hole Bananen**.

I hope this helps you.
Your translations were not bad, you are on a good way of learning German!

Comment: Thanks a lot @kuma . When I write "some around" I mean to say that someone around is cooking. Its not in the question kind of sense. So do you think "Jemand in der Nahe" is good translation?

Comment: In what context do you want to use that sentence? If you mean by "someone around is cooking" something like "there is someone nearby that is cooking" then you say "Jemand in der Nähe kocht". But if you want to say for example that your mother is around (e.g. in your house) and she is cooking, then you say "Jemand ist da und kocht". If you say "In der Nähe", it means "nearby" and "da" is "there" or "around". So it depends on the context that you want to use that phrase.

Comment: @orange14 Awesome!